# How to push the condition based value in existing array in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.6

I am having three arrays

1. topicsSelected
2. relavantGroups
3. topicAssingned

```php
$topicsSelected = [ "T-100","T-600"];

$relavantGroups = [
                    [ "id" => "G-001","name" => "3 A","active" => false ], 
                    ["id" => "G-002","name" => "3 B","active" => false]  
                  ];

$topicAssingned = [
    "G-001" => [
        "groupID" => "G-001",
        "groupName" => "3 A",
        "topics" => [
            "T-100" => [
                "topicID" => "T-100"
            ],
            "T-200" => [
                "topicID" => "T-200"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "G-002" => [
        "groupID" => "G-002",
        "groupName" => "3 B",
        "topics" => [
            "T-400" => [
                "topicID" => "T-400"
            ],
            "T-500" => [
                "topicID" => "T-500"
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

`$topicsSelected` array values at least one value should present `$topicAssingned` means based on groupID, i have to push one value to `$relavantGroups` like  **disable : D**  suppose value not present means **disable : A**

Expected output:

```
[
     "id" => "G-001",
    "name" => "3 A",
    "active" => false,
    "disable" => "D"
],
[
     "id" => "G-002",
    "name" => "3 B",
    "active" => false,
    "disable" => "A"
]
```

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: @vivek_23,$topicsSelected array values(T-100 or T-600) at least one value should present in $topicAssingned array, based on groupID(G-001). $topicAssingned under topics , topicID : T-100 is present , so "disable" : "D"

Comment: @vivek_23,$topicsSelected array values(T-100 or T-600) at least one value should present in $topicAssingned array, based on groupID(G-002). $topicAssingned under topics , topicID : T-600 is not present , so "disable" : "A"

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are asking and the code is a bit weird but I'll give it a try.
First fix your array declaration - you should use `=>` and not `:`;

You have to Iterate over the `$relavantGroups` and for each element iterate the `$topicAssingned` array. Then perform a simple comparison to see if the group `Id` is present and you are done!

**Here is my solution (quick and dirty):** [You can see it here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a632acf788a96227c70b95c2b76e7a1f969883a)

```
foreach ($relavantGroups as &$g) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($topicAssingned as $key => $assigned) {
        if ($key === $g["id"] && is_array($assigned["topics"])) {
            foreach ($assigned["topics"] as $topic) {
                if (in_array($topic["topicID"], $topicsSelected)) {
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $g["disable"] = $found ? "D" : "A";
}
var_dump($relavantGroups);
```

Updated the solution - note that I'm using `in_array()` to determine if the `topicID` is present. That mean that any value that is in the `$topicsSelected` array will affect the result.

Hope I helped.

**This will output (based one your example):**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> array(4) {
    ["id"]=> string(5) "G-001"
    ["name"]=> string(3) "3 A"
    ["active"]=> bool(false)
    ["disable"]=> string(1) "D"
  }
  [1]=> array(4) {
    ["id"]=> string(5) "G-002"
    ["name"]=> string(3) "3 B"
    ["active"]=> bool(false)
    ["disable"]=> string(1) "A"
  }
}
```

Comment: `$topicsSelected` array values(T-100 or T-600) at least one value should present in `$topicAssingned` array, based on groupID(G-001).
`$topicAssingned` under **topics** , `topicID` : T-100 is present , so "disable" : "D".

Comment: `$topicsSelected` array values(T-100 or T-600) at least one value should present in `$topicAssingned` array, based on groupID(G-002).
`$topicAssingned` under **topics** , `topicID` : T-600 is not present , so "disable" : "A".

Comment: I don't get it... What happen if the both are present??? - and in your example `"G-002"`don't have neither one and still is D.

Comment: Yes `G-002` is don't have topicID so "disable" : "A", i has updated my expected output please check

Comment: if the both are present also "disable" : "D"

Comment: @Prasanna I think I understand now - check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$topicsSelected = [ "T-100","T-600"];

$relavantGroups = [
    [ "id" => "G-001","name" => "3 A","active" => false ],
    ["id" => "G-002","name" => "3 B","active" => false]
];

$topicAssigned = [
    "G-001" => [
        "groupID" => "G-001",
        "groupName" => "3 A",
        "topics" => [
            "T-100" => [
                "topicID" => "T-100"
            ],
            "T-200" => [
                "topicID" => "T-200"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "G-002" => [
        "groupID" => "G-002",
        "groupName" => "3 B",
        "topics" => [
            "T-400" => [
                "topicID" => "T-400"
            ],
            "T-500" => [
                "topicID" => "T-500"
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

$topic_selected_map = [];

foreach($topicsSelected as $each_topic){
    $topic_selected_map[$each_topic] = true;
}

$relevant_group_map = [];

foreach($relavantGroups as $each_group){
    $relevant_group_map[$each_group['id']] = $each_group;
}

$result = [];

foreach($topicAssigned as $each_assigned_topic){
    if(!isset($relevant_group_map[$each_assigned_topic['groupID']])) continue;

    $topics_not_found = true;
    foreach($each_assigned_topic['topics'] as $each_topic => $topic_details){
        if(isset($topic_selected_map[$each_topic])){
            $topics_not_found = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    $result[] = [
        'id' => $each_assigned_topic['groupID'],
        'name' => $each_assigned_topic['groupName'],
        'active' => $relevant_group_map[$each_assigned_topic['groupID']]['active'],
        'disable' => ($topics_not_found === true ? 'A' : 'D')
    ];
}


print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => G-001
            [name] => 3 A
            [active] => false
            [disable] => D
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => G-002
            [name] => 3 B
            [active] => false
            [disable] => A
        )

)
```

- First, make a map(associative array) of values of `$topicsSelected`. Same goes for `$relavantGroups`. This is to make the check more efficient. See more on [Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).
- Now, iterate over `$topicAssigned` and then iterate over each group's `topics` inside it. Now, check if a topic exists inside `$topicsSelected` using a simple [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function. If yes, we disable them, else we don't.